# How to handle protocol buffers ZeroCopyInputStream EOF using ParseDelimitedFromCodedStream

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I am using the following code to parse a "wrapper_message" out of a raw_input_stream_ (which is a ZeroCopyInputStream):

```
    std::istringstream input_stream_;
    raw_input_stream_ = std::make_unique<IstreamInputStream>(&input_stream_);
    pb::Wrapper wrapper_message;
    
    success = ParseDelimitedFromZeroCopyStream(&wrapper_message, raw_input_stream_.get(), &clean_eof);
    if (success)
        ProcessMessage(wrapper_message);
    else
        if (!clean_eof)
        {
             // I want to *Backup(bytes_from_last_truncated_message)*. 
             // I mean I want to point back the read position to the begining 
             // of the truncated message (truncated due to an EOF).
        }
```

This is my issue. I am not able to use raw_input_stream_.get()->Backup(count) because it fails with the following exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
what():  CHECK failed: backup_bytes_ == 0 && buffer_.get() != NULL:  
BackUp() can only be called after Next().
```

I would like to know if there is any way to "rollback" the buffer to the previous call to ParseDelimitedFromZeroCopyStream.

**EDIT:**
I digged into the protobuf source code and the issue seems to be here in **zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:** in FreeBuffer().

```
// Read new data into the buffer.
buffer_used_ = copying_stream_->Read(buffer_.get(), buffer_size_);
  if (buffer_used_ <= 0) {
    // EOF or read error.  We don't need the buffer anymore.
    if (buffer_used_ < 0) {
      // Read error (not EOF).
      failed_ = true;
    }
  FreeBuffer();
  return false;
```

FreeBuffer() reset the buffer (buffer_.reset()). Then the exception is thrown here, trying to use Backup (rollback failed bytes):

```
void CopyingInputStreamAdaptor::BackUp(int count) {
  GOOGLE_CHECK(backup_bytes_ == 0 && **buffer_.get() != NULL**)
      << " BackUp() can only be called after Next().";
  GOOGLE_CHECK_LE(count, buffer_used_)
      << " Can't back up over more bytes than were returned by the last call"
         " to Next().";
  GOOGLE_CHECK_GE(count, 0) << " Parameter to BackUp() can't be negative.";

  backup_bytes_ = count;
}
```

Is it a bug?

**EDIT 2: I tried the suggestion of seeking the underlying stream, but it didn't work**

Here is the code:

```
pb::Wrapper wrapper_message;

long rollback_position = input_stream_.tellg();

success = ParseDelimitedFromZeroCopyStream(&wrapper_message, raw_input_stream_.get(), &clean_eof);

if (success)
    ProcessMessage(wrapper_message);
else
{  
    if(!clean_eof)
    {
        input_stream_.seekg(rollback_position);
    }
}
```

Regards!

Comment: You cannot back off arbitrarily far in a `ZeroCopyInputStream` - only as far as the buffer size passed to the most recent `Next` call. You may be able to seek the underlying `input_stream_` back to the original position. What type is `input_stream_`?

Comment: I would like just to backup previous Next. However, the Backup method seems to work only if the input_stream_ didn't reach the end. Once the end is reached (in the code buffer_used_ = 0), Next() calls FreeBuffer() which resets buffer_ disabling further calls to Backup. input_stream_ is a std::istringstream.

Comment: What I want to accomplish here is, if the end of istringstream has a truncated message, backup those bytes to have the chance to append the rest of the message to the istringstream, later, and then parse again from it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to seek the underlying input_stream_ but it didn't work. I was able to seek input_stream_ but the ZeroCopyInputStream didn't notice, and continue reading from its last point (position_). I edited the answer to include the code I used.

Comment: After seeking in `input_stream_`, you'd need to drop and recreate the `ZeroCopyInputStream` that wraps it. This way you'd be in the exact same state you had before this whole parse attempt.

Comment: I fixed it last friday, in a similar way, but using ArrayInputStream, and it works. However the ArrayInputStream solution does not convince me. Should be better to use ZeroCopyInstream instead and recreate it after each seeking?. Regards.

Comment: I now see that `input_stream_` is of type `std::istringstream`. That details was added later and wasn't available initially. Presumably, this means you have your data in a `std::string` to begin with. In this case, `ArrayInputStream` makes the most sense - it can work directly on the string's underlying data, there's no point wrapping it in multiple layers.

Comment: I have the data in a const char* coming from a socket recv. I have both version running right now, I mean using ArrayInputStream and ZeroCopyInputStream. Since I am "streaming" from a socket recv() I am wonder which technique should be better. In my ZeroCopyInputStream soluition I am using a std::istringstream and rdbuf() to append data to it. If there is an issue (eof for example) I perform a seekg() to the last "valid" position. waiting for the "following" append to occur (socket recv()).

Comment: You can append to a plain `std::string` just as well. It's unclear what benefit you get from using `istringstream`

Comment: For the ArrayInputStream I am using a plain std::string. However with the ZeroCopyInputStream version I have to provide a std:istringstream in order to create an IstreamInputStream which is a ZeroCopyInputStream.

Comment: I fixed the issue using ArrayInputStream. However I found an issue in google::protobuf::util::ParseDelimitedFromCodedStream. If the last bytes on the buffer belongs (potentially partially) to the varint32 which is the next message size, the function returns clean_eof = true, which is not true, skipping those bytes, causing an error when reading the following message. I am performing more tests before submit the bug.

Comment: Far as I can tell [from the implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.cc), `ParseDelimitedFromCodedStream` sets `clean_eof` to `true` in one an only one case - it if failed without consuming a single byte; that is, failed to read even the length prefix. I suspect you are mis-interpreting the observed behavior of your program.